# List item in Semantic UI with image pushes text down

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

Semantic UI website shows an example of lists with items containing an image to the left.

http://semantic-ui.com/elements/list.html

It works fine, except when I use a long enough text, the text then goes under the image.

That does not happen, when I use an icon instead of the image.

Compare this with an image http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GjLGVx

```
<div class="ui list">
  <div class="item">
    <img class="ui avatar image" src="http://semantic-ui.com/images/avatar2/small/rachel.png">
    <div class="content">
      <a class="header">Rachel</a>
      <div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Looks like this:

[image: Ugly]

And this with an icon http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pEBKrX

```
<div class="ui list">
  <div class="item">
    <i class="ui apple icon"></i>
    <div class="content">
      <a class="header">Rachel</a>
      <div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

[image: Good]

Can anyone fix the image version so that the text is shown right to the image just like in the icon version?

The browser is Chrome 54.0.2840.71 (64-bit)

Answer (score 1):

Hey you can also do like this

```css
.item{
  border:1px solid red;
  width:300px;
  position:relative;
}
img{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
a{
  color:blue;}
.content {
 margin-left:50px;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="ui list">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://www.apple.com/home/images/og.jpg?201608151252" height=50px width=50px>
 
    <div class="content">
      <a class="header" href="#">Rachel</a>
      <div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so you say it is a bug in semantic-ui and it cant be done the semantic-ui way?

Comment: Im saying you need to tweak a bit to get the desired result

Comment: Hey we can also do it using position:absolute,modified the code check it now